# How to install a java enabled browser in ubuntu 16+?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, java, plugins, firefox-extensions

I want to run an Indian govt website and submit an application by attaching a digital signature using a USB crypto token I posses. The ideal requirement of the site is 32bit java 7 enabled browser.

I use the method suggested here to run portable firefox https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192228
In order for firefox to recognise java, I create a symbolic link to java plugin library explained here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_plugin.html

the following are the issues I'm facing

1. I tried using 64-bit firefox portable with default java(java 8) but I couldn't get Firefox to recognise java plugin and it doesn't appear in the plugin section of firefox.
2. I haven't been able to run a 32-bit portable version of firefox using the above mention method.
3. When I install java using rpm packages it is not recognised by the system and java -version command doesn't show installed java, leaving me with default java.
4. Java 7 can no longer be installed through apt and I have to download the source tar.gz. How to get ubuntu to recognise java 7 from an extracted tar.
5. Although I had no real hope for it but it has worked the best so far. I used wine to install firefox 48 and java 7 both 32-bit. Firefox does recognise java but the site still doesn't pickup my usb token.

Ideally, I want to get either firefox.v48 32-bit or chrome.v41 32-bit and java-7 32-bit working in my ubuntu 16.04 64 bit system.
Any help appreciated